# Metadata property search on date cannot search single day

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

Whenever we try to search on any metadata property that is a date type and use "=" so as to only return documents on that date we always receive:

> Your query included only common words and / or characters, which were
>   removed. No results are available. Try to add query terms.

examples that return the above result:

- ModifiedDate="27/01/2014"
- ModifiedDate="01/27/2014"
- ModifiedDate="27-01-2014"
- (ModifiedDate>="27/01/2014" AND ModifiedDate<="27/01/2014")

I have checked the noise files for English US and they do not contain anything relating to dates/numbers.

These work though but return more documents than preferred obviously:

- ModifiedDate>="27/01/2014"
- ModifiedDate<="27/01/2014"

Answer (score 0):

In my environment the property is called: LastModifiedTime and the following query works:

```
lastmodifiedtime=17.06.2014
```